# GreenDao queryBuilder().list() returns deleted entity

Tags: android, caching, orm, greendao

I am using GreenDao in my application and currently encountering an interesting problem.

Firstly I deleted an entity Item "A" (ID=1) and run it in transaction using runInTx() from DaoSession.

After deletion, my application goes back to list of items and expectedly found out my item is removed. 
Then I add a new item entity Item "B" into DB, when I went back to the list again using EntityDao.QueryBuilder().list() I found out entity Item "A" was listed again, not entity Item "B".

When I checked the DB, entity Item "B" was created using the same ID=1. Listing all Items seems to me will return cached entities.

I did the following DaoSession.clear() after delete, however it still results in cached deleted entity.

Anyone has any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem.

The issue is that I was DaoSession.clear() inside delete activity, call activity.finish() then go back to list item activity.

It was clearly activity management issue as I designed each activity to have its own DaoSession. Each instance of DaoSession will contain session cache of GreenDao objects.

More information of GreenDao's session cache can be read [here](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/sessions/)

So the solution is clearing List Item activity's DaoSession after delete activity is finished.

Comment: Can you make it more clear?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890400/clear-data-from-cache-using-greendao/23891456#comment36806212_23891456