# Clear Data From Cache Using GreenDAO

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

In my app, there are 4 `Activities`  starting from activities 1 to 4.

`Database` creation takes place in activity1 and values are updated in activities 2, activities 3 etc.But when i moves back to activities  using `finish()` from activities 3 to activities 2 ,it wont shown the updated value because of cache.(Cant able to show the updated value)

i tried `daosession.clear()`  ,but it is not clearing the data.

So how to clear old cache and reload the data using `GreenDAO`.

In all these activities , i used separate session .See sample code

Suppose current activity is `CaptureLocationDetails` class

```
public static CaptureLocationDetails getInstance()
{
    return instance;
}

   openHelper = new DevOpenHelper(MyApplication.getInstances());
    //openHelper.openDatabase();
    db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);

    daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();



-----

----


 daoSession.getUserDao().update(entity);
```

then

`GetMap` class  (Next Activity)

```
DevOpenHelper openHelper = new DevOpenHelper(MyApplication.getInstances());
    db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
    daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
```

### ----

```
 upPackLinear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
        {

            //DaoSession.this.clear();


            //daoSession.clear();
            finish();

            CaptureLocationDetails.getInstance().daoSession.clear();

        }
    });
```

But when i returned back to `CaptureLocationDetails` class , it loads value from cache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with 2 approaches.

### 1.  `startActivityForResult()` approach

Follow the following steps. If confused, you may check [this](http://techblogon.com/android-start-activity-for-result-example/) tutorial.

1. start your 2nd `Activity` using `startActivityForResult()`
2. `Override` the `onActivityResult()` in the 1st `Activity`. There, clear the DB cache and refetch the data.
3. before `finish()` call in 2nd `Activity`, call `setResult()`.

### 2.  `onResume()` approach

- clear the DB cache and load the data in `onResume()`.
- This way every time the `Activity` shows up, data will be fetched. It's not efficient because every time your `Activity` comes to foreground, `onResume()` is called.

Comment: Actually each time values are saved to dB before going to next Activity.So problem is once I comes back to previous activity,dB is not fetching the updated value because of cache since I'm using greendao.

Comment: @KP_ are you updating new values to the DB? If not then just rely on `startActivityForResult()` and it will still work.

Comment: Yeah..Caching is a feature of GreenDAO.It is completely related to it.not startActivityForResult() or anything

Comment: @KP_ then as I told you, you could use `startActivityForResult()`. It is used when you want to send messages between `Activities`. For example, `Activity` A starts `Activity` B, and when B ends it sends something back to A by calling `setResult()` before `finish()` call.

Comment: Anyways it is not  updating cache

Comment: That's a problem with the `GreenDAO` and not sending/updating `Activities` :)

Comment: In each activity, i used "daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();"  and  i dont know where to call this daoSession.clear().I tried  this function before finish() in the next activity.But no use...

Comment: @KP_ share the code in your question. Show where you are clearing the cache, calling `finish()` and updating the DB.

Comment: Why was this answer selected? Did it solve the problem?

Comment: @8oh8 yes it did. The problem was that the cache didn't update.

Comment: Do I clear session by calling daoSession.clear()? I think I tried this. Definitely didn't try it on onStart(), right now I have it onResume(). Even tried assigning daoSession = daoMaster.new session()  there. Will try session.clear()  on onStart next time I'm coding.

Comment: @8oh8 `onResume()` will be called every time the Activity comes to foreground. I'll fix it in the answer. And, are you re-fetching the data in `onResume()`? If not then you need to.

Comment: @Sufian Hey I was re-fetching the data, and it was working correctly but I wasn't notifying my arrayAdapter so it's my bad. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution is**

1:Just moves  from one next activity to  the previous activity using Intent(**Not through finish()** )

It clears old cache and loads the updated value..

Hope this  helps somebody.. :)